# Как создать окно в игре например (dota2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу сформулировать верно запрос в интернете, хотелось бы понять как интегрировать графику в игру с помощью ЯП: Python?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вам поможет [что-то типа такого](https://docs.opendota.com/), но если вы хотите написать программу которая взаимодействует внутри игры с игрой в онлайне, то вряд ли у вас это выйдет не будучи заблокированным Valve

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).